# Confused about the script embed in ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

I'm trying to get started with ng2-charts. I've never seen a .js embed from the node_modules directory before, as they specify [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/):

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

I'm using Angular CLI. As far as I understood, the node_modules directory isn't served, and if it is, I do not know how to access it.

I did try duplicating those packages and linking to them in src/, but I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at chart.js:4
```

I have no clue how this is supposed to work, so I tried to find a working example. Even in the [project on Github](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts), the only examples of this embed are in the ReadMe files.

Comment: My guess: chart.js uses nodejs as a base which means that you need that for require to exist. Since you are referencing it from template i would try to reference it from inside your app.js

Comment: Have you added your library `chart.js` in `map` like this: `'ng2-select': 'node_modules/ng2-select',`?

Comment: try following this documentation and let us know:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started

Comment: Did you ever solve this ? I am trying to get bg2-charts working in an Angular2 app and I am getting the same error. So far, every solution I have found online has failed.

Comment: import { Chart } from 'chart.js';